# Does .Net Framework Version dictate your WPF version?

Tags: wpf, version, wpf-4.0, .net-4.0

Seems like this is a dumb question, but I need something... substantial.

I have an application in VS2010 whose target framework is 3.5.  If I change it to use .Net framework 4.0, will it automatically "update" to use WPF 4.0 as well?

I could not find this stated explicitly anywhere, and the closest thing I found was "All future releases of WPF will be part of the .NET Framework." which seems to imply this, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If you are using .NET Framework 4.0 then you are using WPF4.  I don't think they are independent.  They have always been tied to .NET releases.  It does get a little configuring when people call .NET 3.0 WPF 1.0 as that was the initial release of WPF.

But to a developer, only .NET version matters as that defines what WPF API changes/version you are using.

Comment: Great thanks!  That's what I thought too.  I was just worried that there would be somewhere that I'd have to specify the WPF version if it wasn't bound to the .Net version, but this makes everything cleaner.